# :last-child ignore nested structure

Tags: jquery

I have keyboard layout. Each row has a structure similar to provided -  there can be charButtons (inside "charRow") and functional  buttons   - direct  children of "keyboard-row"
On click I need to check that button (element of  type a) is the last in row = no  matter whether it is direct child or  nested.

```
<div class="keyboard-row">
  <a href="#" id="langSwitch" class="largeKey" lang-code="en">ENG</a>
  <div class="charRow">
    <a href="#" class="key" id="key2">1</a>
    <a href="#" class="key" id="key3">2</a>
    <a href="#" class="key" id="key4">3</a>
    <a href="#" class="key" id="key5">4</a>
    <a href="#" class="key" id="key6">5</a>
    <a href="#" class="key" id="key7">6</a>
    <a href="#" class="key" id="key8">7</a>
    <a href="#" class="key" id="key9">8</a>
    <a href="#" class="key" id="key10">9</a>
    <a href="#" class="key" id="key11">0</a>
    <a href="#" class="key" id="key12">_</a>
  </div>
  <a href="#" id="enter" class="largeKey">Search</a>
</div>
<div class="keyboard-row">
  <div class="charRow">
    <a href="#" class="key" id="key1">A</a>
    <a href="#" class="key" id="key2">S</a>
    <a href="#" class="key" id="key3">D</a>
    <a href="#" class="key" id="key4">F</a>
    <a href="#" class="key" id="key5">G</a>
    <a href="#" class="key" id="key6">H</a>
    <a href="#" class="key" id="key7">J</a>
    <a href="#" class="key" id="key8">K</a>
    <a href="#" class="key" id="key9">L</a>
  </div>
</div>
```

Using `$(e.target).is(".keyboard-row a:last-child")` returns true both for element with id "enter" and "key12". for first row  and "key9" for  the second  row sample.

Is there a way to change the code so that to get only element with id "enter" for the first row and "key9" for  the  second?

Comment: try this: `$(e.target).is(".keyboard-row a#enter")`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

this should works

```
var $el = $(e.target);
var result = $el.is($el.parents('.keyboard-row:first').find("a:last"));
console.log(result); // true only for #enter and #key9
```

Answer (score 2):

You need to get the current row, and search only within that row for the last `a`. Then you can test whether this target is that element.

```js
$("a").click(function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  var curRow = $(this).closest(".keyboard-row");
  alert($(this).is($("a:last", curRow)));
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="keyboard-row">
  <a href="#" id="langSwitch" class="largeKey" lang-code="en">ENG</a>
  <div class="charRow">
    <a href="#" class="key" id="key2">1</a>
    <a href="#" class="key" id="key3">2</a>
    <a href="#" class="key" id="key4">3</a>
    <a href="#" class="key" id="key5">4</a>
    <a href="#" class="key" id="key6">5</a>
    <a href="#" class="key" id="key7">6</a>
    <a href="#" class="key" id="key8">7</a>
    <a href="#" class="key" id="key9">8</a>
    <a href="#" class="key" id="key10">9</a>
    <a href="#" class="key" id="key11">0</a>
    <a href="#" class="key" id="key12">_</a>
  </div>
  <a href="#" id="enter" class="largeKey">Search</a>
</div>
<div class="keyboard-row">
  <div class="charRow">
    <a href="#" class="key" id="key1">A</a>
    <a href="#" class="key" id="key2">S</a>
    <a href="#" class="key" id="key3">D</a>
    <a href="#" class="key" id="key4">F</a>
    <a href="#" class="key" id="key5">G</a>
    <a href="#" class="key" id="key6">H</a>
    <a href="#" class="key" id="key7">J</a>
    <a href="#" class="key" id="key8">K</a>
    <a href="#" class="key" id="key9">L</a>
  </div>
</div>
```

But why not just:

```
$(e.target).is("#enter")
```

Comment: Thanks, but I guess I was not clear enough. I  have corrected my  question.